# Translating JQuery to Javascript: Hamburger Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

Trying to rewrite this JQuery into Javascript for the hamburger animation.

```
 <div class="hamburgerLines" id="nav-icon">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

```
#nav-icon{
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ed1250;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


#nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

What I've come up with so far is:

```
const menuBtn = document.querySelectorAll('hamburgerLines');
let menuOpen = false;

menuBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  if(!menuOpen){
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  }else{
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
})
```

But that doesn't work. It also doesn't work if I use `getElementByID('#nav-icon');` instead. Do I need to create a loop to go through all of the span items? Am I not taking the keyword this into account? (still a little new to JS and the this keyword is a concept I'm still working to understand completely).

Comment: Use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`. And you need a `.` at the beginning of the selector to select a class.

Comment: And when you use `getElementById()` you *don't* put `#` at the beginning.

Comment: You can use `menuBtn.classList.toggle('open')` instead of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word `this` refers to the current object.

For example:

```
<button onclick="btnClick(this)">test</button>
<script>
    function btnClick(button)
    {
        alert(button.innerText)
    }
</script>
```

```js
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('nav-icon');
menuBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  if(!menuBtn.classList.contains("open")){
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
  }else{
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
  }
});
```

```css
#nav-icon{
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ed1250;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


#nav-icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(2),#nav-icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav-icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav-icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburgerLines" id="nav-icon">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```